# Функция для отправки запроса к серверу

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch

Оптимизирую свое приложение, в файле для описания всех запросов к серверу написала вот такую функцию

```
mainReques = async (url, method, body) => {
    try {
      const getAuthFlag = () => {
        if (this.token) {
          return { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8', Authorization: `Token ${getToken()}` };
        }
        return { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' };
      };
      const request = await fetch(url, {
        method,
        headers: getAuthFlag(),
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
      const resp = await request.json();
      return resp;
    } catch {
      throw new Error();
    }
  };
```

Использую ее при попытке авторизации:

```
authentication = (email, pass) => {
    try {
      const body = {
        user: {
          email,
          password: pass,
        },
      };
      this.mainRequest(`${какой-то url}`, 'POST', body);
    } catch {
      throw new Error();
    }
  };
```

В компоненте вызываю так:

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    ApiServices.authentication(data.email, data.password)
      .then((resp) => {
        getUserData(resp.user.username, resp.user.image); // сохраняю данные пользователя в стор
        auth(true); // меняю флаг авторизации
        saveToken(resp.user.token); // сохраняю токен пользователя 
      })
      .catch(() => message.warning('Enter login and password'));
  };
```

Мне кажется такой код логичным, но при авторизации в браузере выскакивает вот такая ошибка :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понимаю, ошибка происходит на уровне запроса. Вопрос в том, как ее исправить?

Comment: А ответ с сервера точно приходит?

Comment: Судя по всему then не видит промис

Comment: Ответ приходит, из-за ошибки в запросе (я так предполагаю), вместо промиса выходит ошибка, поэтому then не отрабатывает. Вопрос в том, как исправить это.

Comment: `authentication` ничего не возвращает, поэтому и `undefined`

Comment: @Chilik ваша функция падает из за значения undefined, следовательно вам нужно либо поймать ошибку с помощью catch, либо что то вроде этого getUserData(resp?.user?.username, resp?.user?.image);

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы authentication заработала так как вы хотите, она должна вернуть Promise. Попробуйте добавить слово async перед объявлением функции authentication. Таким образом функция неявно вернет Promise

```
const authentication = async (...args) => /*so stuff*/
```

Или явно создайте Promise и верните его:

```
const authentication = (...args) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      // do stuff
      if (all_is_good)
          resolve(result)
      else 
          reject("something bad")
                
})
}
```

Обратите внимание, что при явном возвращении Promise функция объявляется без async.